# IO Exception When Generating Signed APK

Tags: android, realm, ioexception

I am trying to create signed APK an android,however I am getting IOException..
Exception is shown below..

```
Warning:io.realm.processor.RealmProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: You are using proguard ? post your build.gradle.

Comment: This problem is happen when your app build version not matched SDK latest version.so update your SDK.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this warnings.but finally adding (-ignorewarnings) using **progaurd-rules.pro** file from my applications.
this problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This bug happens when the versions of SDK, Build Tools and Gradle Plugins doesn't match (in terms of compatibility). The solutions is to verify if you are using the latest versions of them. The gradle plugins are placed in the build.gradle file of the project. Other versions are in the build.gradle file of the module. For example, for SDK 23, you must use the Build Tools 23.0.1 and gradle plugins version 1.3.1.

OR

include this in your Proguard config:

```
-dontwarn javax.lang.model.**
```

Comment: my SDK is 23,Build Tools 23.0.1 and gradle plugin version 1.5.1 but nothing happens.